# twig: display only one image from a JSON array that contains a number of image sets i various sizes with the same key names?

Tags: json, twig

I want to display only one image in my listings.

The JSON structured is like this:

```
Object{3}->T{1}->annoncer[20]->0,1,2,3...{31}->images[13]->0,1,2,3...{6}->small
```

[LINK to JSON structure example](http://diegovega.dk/kea/2semester/json-eks/json-eks.json)

With this twig template code all “small” images get displayed:

```html
    {% for item in T.annoncer %}
    {{item.text}}
            {% for im in item.images %}
                <img src={{im.small}} />                
            {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Any help that points on the right direction is greatly appreciated :)

SOLUTION: To show only one image with the listing the twig template is like this:

```
    {% for item in T.annoncer %}
    {{item.text}}
      <img src={{item.images[0].small}} />
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: is not so clear what you are looking for... only one (the first?) image for any item?  try with `item.images[0].small`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could access to the first element simply as follow:

```
item.images[0].small
```

Comment: thanks Matteo. item.images[0].small was that I was looking for :)